# How can I add personal comments manully in the Grafana according to different person and situations?

Tags: grafana

I have installed a dashboard in the Grafana and I want to add some personal details such as name, fixed date, which project under status `Viewer` according to different people and projects.

For example, using Grafana we monitor each computer.

Alice select `Alice` template and can write down "Alice's computer, 2019-12-17,CPU temperature is high" then take a screenshot to save.

Tomorrow, Bob select `Bob` and write down "Bob's computer, 2019-12-18, Everything is OK except GPU is broken" then take a screenshot to save.

We just want to save pictures with respective comments, but Grafana just supply panels. Are there some plugins to do this function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: I have added an example. Please review it. Thanks